# Database Adjacency List Model - Get all same level parents in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have 2 tables.

```
nodes (nid, ntid, parent, title)
```

`nid` is the node id (primary key) and `ntid` is the foreign key to the table `noteTypes`

`noteTypes (ntid, name)` - this table has only 4 rows

- 1, Book
- 2, Chapter
- 3, Article
- 4, Section

I need to display all the same level parents for a specific node. Example: I receive the nid = 123 which is the id for an Article and I need to fetch all the chapters (to be able to choose where to move the Article in my node.js app)

I've already done it with 3 queries:

1) get parent id for nid=123 (returns 12, which is the id of the parent of the Article)

2) get the parent type for nid=12 (returns 2, which is the Chapter)

3) get all the nodes for the parent type=2 (returns all chapters)

With this database model, can it be done with only 1 query, instead of 3?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the exact levels required, you can create a query (Mysql doesn't allow for recursion which would allow you to dynamically traverse the relationship).

```
SELECT all_articles.*
FROM nodes AS articles
JOIN nodes AS chapter
  ON articles.parent = chapter.nid
JOIN nodes AS all_articles
  ON all_articles.parent = chapter.nid
WHERE articles.nid = 123;
```